# Is there a way to use the build modifier as an animation to be exported to unity in blender?

Tags: blender

I am trying to use the build modifier as an animation to allow objects to appear to materialize

I have attempted to use shape key frames but for that to work you need all modifiers applied.
I have also attempted to use regular keyframes but it doesn't auto key I assume this is because it doesn't count modifiers as a change to the mesh

I'm not entirly sure of what else to do thank you for any help in advance
Kurtis

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Basicaly Blender modifiers can not be used in Unity because Unity does not know nothing about them. If you export your scene to FBX for example every modifier will be aplied during export. Even if you use .blend file in Unity I think it will internaly export models to FBX format nevertheless.

Comment: i'm trying to get the build modifier's animation to be applied to the object i created in the same blender file appling the modifier while in blender seems to save the model on whatever frame it was on when you apply it which doesn't save the animation like i hoped it would

Comment: Do you mean armature modifier? If you have animation working in Blender you need to export the model to FBX with "bake animations" selected in export settings. Also I remember a bug in Unity when animation failed when some bones had 0 scale because bounding bounding box couldn't be made. I don't know if it still there.

Comment: no I mean a modifier called build it changes the way the mesh looks on every frame of the animation but i can't seem to save it with shape keys or such (as it will simply just make the mesh look like it did when I created the key + seperate animations(though seperate animations won't work in unity unless they are shape key themselves(I know because I tried using .blend and fbx))) and directly exporting it (.blend/fbx) doesn't seem to work either

Comment: This is Blender specific modifier which can not be exported to Unity. I don't think there is a way to convert this modifier in any type of animation which would work in Unity. The only option is to create this functionality in Unity eaither as a script or a material / shader. Tutorial with similar (disolve) effect is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=taMp1g1pBeE

Comment: Thank you this was what I was looking for, I only asked this as I considered as these are both products used in game production maybe there was a way to use animation clips used in blender for use in unity and now I realize this is impossable with the build modifier